# Save and Restore workbench on E4

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4, workbench

in my RCP 3.x-based Client-/Server-Application, I save the workbench state (e.g. open view and editors, window position and size, ...) in a XML file and reload it when the user want. For this I use IWorkbench.saveState and IWorkbench.restoreState.

But after migrating to RCP 4 platform, methods are no longer available. How can I save in an XML file and restore It when the user want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `IWorkbench` doesn't have a `saveState` or `restoreState` method. e4 normally saves the workbench state on exit in the workbench.xmi file in the metadata.

Comment: I want to save and load an xmi file like the workbench.xmi, but I need to control the load and the save of this files. The user should be able to save and load the perspective layout when he want.

Comment: [This tutoral](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4ModelPersistence/article.html) seems to cover some of that